# Spotify web player on windows stops working over mobile data hotspot

Tags: windows, google-chrome, hotspot, spotify

Sure hotspot over mobile data as wifi is not the best alternative, but with 4G and 5G speeds are enough to avoid installing Wifi on county home.

the thing is, as long as I play Spotify, it stops working after a while, refeshing the page works, but the player does not reproduce any sound, sometimes it gets playing again after few minutes, othertimes even closing and reopening chrome doesn't help

I check with ping 1.1.1.1 -t, and conection does not seems to be the problem. I check with developers tool -> network, and it does not seems anything wrong.

It just get unresponsive, and it doesn't do that when I am conected with WIFI.

what can i look more ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago I remember a similar behaviour in another app, this is becouse vendor (spotify, whoever) implements device control (where is running, check windows, tablet, etc) and jumps-counts for IP (to check if it is direct conection, or shared data). Objective: make you install the app on the main device, your phone. Solution: not so much at least you want to start messing with middelware routers and modify packages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).